# Opcode for identifying switch case in javassist

Tags: java, reflection, asmx, javassist

How to find the op-code for identifying  switch case in a java class using javassist or asm.

I used the Below Snippet

```
List methods = lClassFile.getMethods();
        for (Object m : methods) {
            MethodInfo lMethodInfo = (MethodInfo) m;
            System.out.println("method name: " + lMethodInfo.getName());
            CodeAttribute ca = lMethodInfo.getCodeAttribute();
            for (CodeIterator ci = ca.iterator(); ci.hasNext();) {
                int index = ci.next();
                int op = ci.byteAt(index);

                if (op == Opcode.TABLESWITCH) {
                    int a1 = ci.s16bitAt(index + 1);
                    String fieldrefType = " " + lClassFile.getConstPool().getFieldrefType(a1);
                    String fieldName = " " + lClassFile.getConstPool().getFieldrefName(a1);
                    String fieldrefClassName = " " + lClassFile.getConstPool().getFieldrefClassName(a1);
                    System.out.println("1 -> FieldrefType = " + fieldrefType + "    field name: " + fieldName + "          FieldrefClassName name: " + fieldrefClassName);
                }
                if (op == Opcode.LOOKUPSWITCH) {
                    int a1 = ci.s16bitAt(index + 1);
                    String fieldrefType = " " + lClassFile.getConstPool().getFieldrefType(a1);
                    String fieldName = " " + lClassFile.getConstPool().getFieldrefName(a1);
                    String fieldrefClassName = " " + lClassFile.getConstPool().getFieldrefClassName(a1);
                    System.out.println("2 -> FieldrefType = " + fieldrefType + "    field name: " + fieldName + "          FieldrefClassName name: " + fieldrefClassName);
                }
            }
        }
```

I got Output as:

```
method name: <init>
method name: execute
2 -> FieldrefType =  null    field name:  null          FieldrefClassName name:  null
1 -> FieldrefType =  null    field name:  null          FieldrefClassName name:  null
method name: validate
2 -> FieldrefType =  null    field name:  null          FieldrefClassName name:  null
2 -> FieldrefType =  null    field name:  null          FieldrefClassName name:  null
method name: postExecute
2 -> FieldrefType =  null    field name:  null          FieldrefClassName name:  null
2 -> FieldrefType =  null    field name:  null          FieldrefClassName name:  null
```

Cant able to get the switch cases values.
Help me please....

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a class with a method that only contains a very simple switch/case statement
2. Compile that class
3. Look at the bytecode using `javap -c MyClass`

The bytecode contains `TABLESWITCH` or `LOOKUPSWITCH` and javassists `Opcode` class has corresponding static fields.